# Spring Web Flow Set Form Input Value

Tags: spring-webflow

I am having a problem assigning a default value to my Spring Form input field. Here's my code

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="employeeDirectoryInfo">
      <form:input type="text" value=${employeeInfo.employee_id}>
</form>
```

The problem is it will say that `value attribute is not valid for tag <form:input>`.

Comment: What is the namespace of 'form'?  I don't recall having to use special tags for spring web-flow.
Is is a html validation error or server side error?
I think we need more information in order to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to insert that value into the input box, or do you want to bind that property to the box (so that a new value typed by the user gets stored in that property)?

If the former, then just use a regular HTML `<input type="text">` and set the value as you are doing.

If the latter, don't use "value", use "path", and leave off the ${}.